# Appsscript deployment

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have created an add-on on Google Apps Script for Google Forms, and I'm having issues with deploying the add-on. It works fine locally, but when I try to deploy it, Google keeps rejecting it without any clear explanations, referring to the documentation that states the onInstall function should call the onOpen function, and the onOpen function should create a menu. Perhaps I have misunderstood something, but I'm following the examples provided in the documentation.
Google Support has also sent a video showing how the add-on works for them. When they open the add-on in a popup window, they only see the Help button, but when I test it locally, I only see the Open Menu option.
Has anyone encountered similar issues? Could you please explain?

[Google see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad1Y7.png)

[I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrPst.png)

function onInstall(e) {
onOpen(e)
};

function onOpen(e) {
const {a , l} = authentication()

let form =  FormApp.getUi().createMenu("AirPet")

```
l && a
? form
.addItem("Open menu", "show_popup").addToUi()
: form
    .addItem("Open menu", "show_popup_expiry")
    .addToUi();
```

};

I have tried changing triggers and also modifying the appsscript.json file, but the result has always been the same.